# Finding powers of matrices that cannot be diagonalised

Tags: matrices

In lessons, we have been taught to find a general solution finding a matrix to the power n by diagonalising it but for an assignment have been asked to find a general formula for:
$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix} ^ n$$
By expending it by hand for the first few terms, I found this to be:
$$\begin{bmatrix}2^n & u_n\\0 & 2^n\end{bmatrix}$$
where $u_n = 2u_{n-1} + 2^{n-1}$

How would I convert this to a general formula and is there a better way to solve this kind of question as several similar ones were set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is useful to write
$$
A 
=
\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then note that the scalar matrix 
$$
S = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}
$$
is in the center of the matrix ring, that is, $S B = B S$ for each matrix $B$, and that the matrix 
$$
N = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
is nilpotent. More precisely, $N^{2} = 0$.

Now you can compute with the usual binomial
$$
A^{n} = (S + N)^{n} = S^{n} + n S^{n-1} N.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: In your example, the factorization
$$
\left[\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
2 & 1 \\
0 & 2 \\
\end{array}\right]
  = \left[\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 2 \\
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$
(with commuting factors) is helpful.